# jquery select the first lis of each ul

Tags: jquery

I need to select the first lis of each ul in this structure:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have this selector: `container.find('div > ul > li:first')` but jquery engine parese first `div > ul > li` and then takes the forst result according to `:first`. But I want the first li of each ul, something like: `div > ul > (li:first)`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the `:first-child` selector:

> **Description: Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.**
>
> *While :first matches only a single element, the :first-child selector can match more than one: one for each parent. This is equivalent to :nth-child(1).*

ref: http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

**Example:**

```
container.find('div ul > li:first-child');
```

*Or if you have multiple levels of `ul` containing `li`'s:*

```
container.find('div > ul > li:first-child');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for jQuery's each() function:

http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$("#yourdiv ul").each(function(){
    $(this).find("li:first");
});
```

Comment: No, I am not! I prefer jquery selector instead of each function - this is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use "first-child" selector on li element

$("ul li:first-child")

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mydiv ul").each(function(){
 $('li:eq(0)',this);
});
```